# Extracting postcode from address

Tags: python, pandas

I have a housing data set with an address column. I want to visualize the correlation between postcode and price. However, the address is in the format `(Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15)`. How do I extract the postcode alone?

I have tried using

```
select substring_index(Address, ',', -1)
```

but it gave me an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-29-2b936e3b990e>", line 1
    select substring_index(Address, ',', -1)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I extract only the postcode, in this case `B15`?

What is the best way to visualize this data, since its a categorical variable not continuous. I think I should group the postcodes, but do I create a dummy?

Comment: Can you add more examples about your data???

Comment: Is this MySQL or Python code?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar, the other columns on the data are < df.columns = ['Property Type','Address','No. of Bathrooms','No. of Bedrooms','No. of Receptions','Nearest Bus Stop', 'Distance to B/Stop', 'House Price']>

Comment: @CodeDifferent , it's Python pls.

Comment: @Datanovice there was a Type Error
TypeError: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'

Comment: @Brytedata please post your sample data, read [mcve]

Comment: @Datanovice if this helps, all the Address info is formatted as in the example below.

Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Norfolk Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B15
Watermarque, 100 Browning Street, Birmingham, West Midlands B16

Comment: @Datanovice I basically want to extract B15, B5, B16, etc.

Comment: @Datanovice thank you for helping. I am not exactly sure what to do. It is a column in a dataframe. Do I copy/paste the entire column? I'm sorry I don't understand what I can do.

Comment: @Datanovice ok.

 Property Type Address No. of Bathrooms No. of Bedrooms No. of Receptions Nearest Bus Stop Distance to B/Stop House Price
8 2 bed Watermarque, 100 Browning Street, Birmingham, ... 1.000 2.000 1.000 Five Ways 0.500 260000.000
9 1 bed Waterfront Walk, Birmingham B1 1.000 1.000 1.000 Five Ways 0.400 195000.000
10 1 bed Hagley Road, Edgbaston, Birmingham B16 1.000 1.000 1.000 Five Ways 0.300 132950.000
12 2 bed Blucher Street, Birmingham B1 1.000 2.000 1.000 Birmingham New Street 0.300 220000.000

Comment: @Brytedata can you remove the comments from above and add it to your post? make sure you format the code too.

Comment: Wait a sec! @Datanovice, I just realized it has already been solved with the code shared below.

df["PostCode"] = df["Address"].str.extract(r"([A-Z]\d+)")

Thank you man. I appreciate your efforts. I was at your Office at Ricoh in December for that Power BI meetup. I live 5 mins away actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data are in a pandas DataFrame you can use the function extract() like this :

`df["PostCode"] = df["Address"].str.extract(r"([A-Z]\d+)")`

The function `extract()` uses the regexp to extract the first occurence of a capital letter followed by a one or several numbers representing the postcode you need.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that and got this notification...

C:\Users\Dell pc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Comment: Wait a sec! This actually did it. I just discovered now. Thank you so much man.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if given AB42 which is valid for the first part of a postcode?

Comment: @v25 that will actually be interesting to test.

Comment: @v25 Of course this regexp only matches a postcode like B15, B16,... for a postcode like AB42 regexp would be : `([A-Z]?[A-Z]\d+)` wich means : 0 or 1 capital letter (specified with `?`char), followed by a capital letter followed by one or several numbers